# Twilio twiml instruction not executing within Flask.redirect

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-twiml

I cannot, for the life of me, get Twilio to execute the twiml instructions within a Flask.redirect. I cannot see anything wrong when I execute the query via Postman, so what am I missing? I can also see the redirect within the console outputs from Flask.

The expected behaviour is that when an outbound call is answered (CallStatus == 'in-progress') the call is redirected to a greeting message. What really happens is that the call lasts for 5 seconds——which is defined in dial() to ensure that Twilio has enough time to react——and the, hangs-up.

I have even tried incorporating a very long pause verb of a 100 seconds into the returned response within greeting(), but that was simply ignored.

So... what am I missing? Any insights would be appreciated.

```
@app.route("/call/dail/<number>", methods=['POST'])
def dial(number):
    call = client.calls.create(
                        status_callback='http://<tunnel>.ngrok.io/call/status_update',
                        status_callback_method='GET',
                        status_callback_event=['initiated', 'answered', 'completed'],
                        twiml='<Response><Pause length="5"/></Response>',
                        to=number,
                        from_=from_number
                    )

    return call.sid

@app.route("/call/status_update", methods=['GET'])
def call_status_update():

   called_number = request.values.get("Called")
   callsid = request.values.get("CallSid")
   callstatus = request.values.get("CallStatus")

   if callstatus == 'in-progress':
      return redirect(url_for('greeting'))

   return "Waiting for someone to pickup..."

@app.route("/call/greeting", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def greeting():
    response = VoiceResponse()

    wait_message = 'This is a greeting.'
    response.say(wait_message)

    return Response(str(response), 200, mimetype="application/xml")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the following TwiML when the call is answered:

`<Response><Pause length="5"/></Response>` and then the call hangs up. You can either use TwiML to [redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/redirect) to another URL or use the [URL parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) of the calls resource and point to the `/call/greeting` URL.

When Twilio runs out of TwiML to execute, the call ends. You got to keep feeding it TwiML. Note, s[tatusCallbacks do not control the call flow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#status-callbacks-in-your-response) (so Twilio will not execute any TwiML returned by a statusCallback).

- Side Note: typo here: `/call/dail/<number>` (dial)

Comment: So the only option would be to update the call directly with something like below to get it into a flow:
`call = client.calls(CallSid).update(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>')`

Comment: The 5 second pause verb was to give the statusCallback enough time to react.